# How to track the Latitude and Longitude at the center of a MapView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I would like to create a MapView which keeps track of the longitude and latitude at the center of the MapView, and stores it in two state variables. How can I track the latitude/longitude in such a way?

I've tried using the `region` to see if the `center` updates with the map movements, but unfortunately it doesn't:

```swift
@State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.75773, longitude: -73.985708), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
```

```swift
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
                showsUserLocation: true,
                annotationItems: getNearbyEvents()
            ) {/* places annotations on the map */}
            }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .accentColor(Color("BlueAccent"))
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.checkLocationServicesEnabled()
                }
            // Displays region center as text... doesn't update with movement :(
            Text("Long: \(region.center.longitude) Lat: \(region.center.latitude)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to check onChange(of: region) ?

Comment: `viewModel.region` is not the same as `region` that is being used in the `Text` use `viewModel.region` instead

Comment: @loremipsum correct, this is the issue. Thanks! Once I changed this, the region was tracking the centerpoint just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewModel.region` is not the same as `region` that is being used in the `Text` use `viewModel.region` instead.

```
Text("Long: \(viewModel.region.center.longitude) Lat: \(viewModel.region.center.latitude)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign region for Map like:

```
region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: self.zoomLevel, longitudeDelta: self.zoomLevel))
```